# combine joined columns of a table with one column of another table into JAVA object

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to combine column of different tables in one entity (object) but im getting a column null even it's not null.
I have two entities called `Operation` and `CanceledOperation`:

Operation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATIONS")
public class Operation{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "Date")
private Timestamp date;

@Transient
private String message;
    
// Other attributes and getters & setters
}
```

CanceledOperation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CANCELED_OPERATIONS")
public class CanceledOperation{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OPERATION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Operation operation;

    @Column(name = "RAINSON")
    private String raison;
//getters & setters
}
```

I'm trying to join the `operation` and `canceledIperation` in order to display the raison for the canceled operation and null non canceled.

this is my native query in my repository:

```
@query(value = "SELECT op.* , co.raison as raison FROM operations op LEFT JOIN canceled_operations co ON op.ID  = co.OPERATION_ID", countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM operations op LEFT JOIN canceled_operations co ON op.ID  = co.OPERATION_ID")
    Page<Operation> getAllOperations(Pageable pageable);
```

and this is how i call my repository:

```
final Page<Operation> operations= operationRepository.getAllOperations(pageable);
```

I tried many solution namely using the `Object[]` instead of `Operation` and I have also added an attribute called raison in the `operation` entity with `@transient` annotation, but even that I still get the raison is null.
can you please give me a hint to solve this issue.
thank in advance.

Comment: I am confused. You return a `Page<Operation>` but operation has no relationship to a Cancelled operation in your doman model (at least not in the code posted). Whatb exactly do you mean by *getting a column null*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found an easy way to do it, instead of doing a complicated query, I have used `findAll()` of each table then I affect the `raison` attribute from `CanceledOperation` to the `message` attribute of `Operation` using `stream` and `map` the two received lists from repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In the CanceledOperation entity, can you give referencedColumnName = "ID" and try?

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OPERATION_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Operation operation;
```